# Just started using python can you please take a look a this? It returns an error… saying ':' expected

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
students_data = {'students': {
        'name': 'Farell',
        'id': '2322345',
        'degree': 'master',
        'start_year': '2020',
        'lecturer_course':
        { 
            'lecturer_name': ['python', 'sql'],
            'lecturer_name1': ['R', 'Java'],
            'lecturer_name2': ['powerBI', 'C++']
        }
    },
    {
        'name': 'Farell',
        'id': '2322345',
        'degree': 'master',
        'start_year': '2020',
        'lecturer_course':
        {
            'lecturer_name': ['python', 'sql'],
            'lecturer_name1': ['R', 'Java'],
            'lecturer_name2': ['powerBI', 'C++']
        }
    }
    {
        'name': 'Farell',
        'id': '2322345',
        'degree': 'master',
        'start_year': '2020',
        'lecturer_course':
        {
            'lecturer_name': ['python', 'sql'],
            'lecturer_name1': ['R', 'Java'],
            'lecturer_name2': ['powerBI', 'C++']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `students_data['students']` supposed to be a list? You have one key followed by a sequence of `dict` objects, which is not a valid `dict` display.

Comment: see a tutorial on dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your dictionary structure. Try working with an [online validator](https://codebeautify.org/python-formatter-beautifier)

```py
d = {
    "students1": {
        "name": "Farell",
        "id": "2322345",
        "degree": "master",
        "start_year": "2020",
        "lecturer_course": {
            "lecturer_name": ["python", "sql"],
            "lecturer_name1": ["R", "Java"],
            "lecturer_name2": ["powerBI", "C  "],
        },
    },
    "students2": {
        "name": "Farell",
        "id": "2322345",
        "degree": "master",
        "start_year": "2020",
        "lecturer_course": {
            "lecturer_name": ["python", "sql"],
            "lecturer_name1": ["R", "Java"],
            "lecturer_name2": ["powerBI", "C  "],
        },
    },
    "students3": {
        "name": "Farell",
        "id": "2322345",
        "degree": "master",
        "start_year": "2020",
        "lecturer_course": {
            "lecturer_name": ["python", "sql"],
            "lecturer_name1": ["R", "Java"],
            "lecturer_name2": ["powerBI", "C  "],
        },
    },
}
```